# Safari has stopped opening

Tags: macos, safari

A friend of mine using Mac OS X 10.14.6 is unable to open Safari suddenly (couldn't pinpoint anything they actively did to cause this), and upon trying to open the browser, an approximately 37-page-long error message comes up with

`Error Code:      0x00000000`

and

```
System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [14212]

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, running initializers
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
Sandbox registration failed: The code signature is not valid: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -67030.)

Application Specific Signatures:
Registration error: The code signature is not valid: The operation couldn’t b

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
```

If I'm not mistaken, the same error code in Windows usually denotes a hardware issue? I'm unaware as to whether there is an antivirus installed on this MacBook.